# SVG not rendering as expected in mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, svg, render

I have generated an SVG image using Inkscape. The image seems to render as expected in the desktop browsers. On mobile it cuts off at the right and the positioning of the elements inside the SVG are off.

Here is the SVG code generated by Inkscape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   viewBox="0 0 216 40"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.5 r10040"
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   sodipodi:docname="Blisscount.svg">
    id=&quot;svg2&quot;
    version=&quot;1.1&quot;
    inkscape:version=&quot;0.48.5 r10040&quot;
    sodipodi:docname=&quot;Blisscount.svg&quot;&gt;

    <defs
   id="defs4" />
<sodipodi:namedview
   id="base"
   pagecolor="#ffffff"
   bordercolor="#666666"
   borderopacity="1.0"
   inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
   inkscape:pageshadow="2"
   inkscape:zoom="3.959798"
   inkscape:cx="108.05012"
   inkscape:cy="13.083765"
   inkscape:document-units="px"
   inkscape:current-layer="g2989"
   showgrid="true"
   inkscape:snap-grids="false"
   inkscape:window-width="1024"
   inkscape:window-height="706"
   inkscape:window-x="-8"
   inkscape:window-y="-8"
   inkscape:window-maximized="1"
   showguides="true"
   inkscape:guide-bbox="true">
  <inkscape:grid
     type="xygrid"
     id="grid3762"
     empspacing="5"
     visible="true"
     enabled="true"
     snapvisiblegridlinesonly="true" />
</sodipodi:namedview>


/&gt;
    <metadata
   id="metadata7">
  <rdf:RDF>
    <cc:Work
       rdf:about="">
      <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
      <dc:type
         rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      <dc:title />
    </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
</metadata>
<g
   inkscape:groupmode="layer"
   id="layer2"
   inkscape:label="block"
   transform="translate(0,-60)" />
<g
   inkscape:label="Layer 1"
   inkscape:groupmode="layer"
   id="layer1"
   transform="translate(0,-1012.3622)"
   style="display:inline">
  <g
     id="g2989">
    <g
       id="g3039">
      <text
         xml:space="preserve"
         style="font-size:50px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#333333;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Calibri;-inkscape-font-specification:Calibri"
         x="37.767944"
         y="1049.1346"
         id="text2985"
         sodipodi:linespacing="125%">lisscount </text>
      <g
         id="g3013">
        <rect
           y="1012.3622"
           x="0"
           height="40"
           width="40"
           id="rect3760"
           style="fill:#0079c1;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none" />
        <text
           xml:space="preserve"
           style="font-size:50px;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;line-height:125%;letter-spacing:0px;word-spacing:0px;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;font-family:Calibri;-inkscape-font-specification:Calibri"
           x="5.3881836"
           y="1048.1581"
           id="text3012"
           sodipodi:linespacing="125%">B</text>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

And this is what it should look like:

> Screen shot from the Inkscape environment.
>   [image]

-

> Screen shot from Firefoxs environment.
>   [image]

-

> This is what it looks like on the mobile browsers.
>   [image]

This is the HTML I am using:

```
<a id="logo_container" href="index.php">
    <object class="main_title" data="../global/img/Blisscount.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
        <img src="../global/img/Blisscount.png" alt="Blisscount" />
    </object>
</a>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#logo_container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 216px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
.main_title {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    vertical-align: middle;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: did you try this: `<div id="mySvg"><svg ...>...</svg></div>` - instead of embedding it into an object? - like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEqeu?editors=100

Comment: I have not tried that as the svg file is so dam long. Why would it make a difference?

Comment: just wondering if mobile browsers have an issue with rendering the `<object>` tag. That's all.  I'm having a second look at your CSS and it looks like your font-size and line-height might be colluding with each other (in either the `<a>` tag or the `<object>` tag.

Comment: Ah i see.. i will give it a go. I have tested the css extensively. definitely not that. I just tried removing one of the font settings and it didn't make a difference. I will get back to you once i have tried putting the SVG in directly

Comment: Another thing is if you look at the images i provided, it looks like the mobile browsers are rendering the text with a larger font or something like that. Possibly a different font as the dot on the 'i' looks square compared to the desktop version where it is round

Comment: I see that, weird... let me see what if I can troubleshoot that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58822/discussion-between-blurfus-and-christopherstrydom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the contents of the SVG, I see the use of Calibri font... maybe your mobile browser does not have it (which would also be the reason why the 'i' looks so square)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the mobile browsers don't support the font-family Calibri therefore rendering the SVG text as Arial.
Arial is a much larger font which explains the text being cut off on the right and the letter 'B' being miss aligned.

Comment: Ha, I was just typing the answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed a missing font.

The solution is to convert your text to an SVG path.
For instance, in Inkscape you'd select your text and go to path->Object to path (or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>)

If that doesn't do it, search for "<your SVG editor> text to outline"